# Maximising sequence of supremum

Tags: calculus

Suppose $\sup_{x \in X}f(x)$ is finite, where $X$ is some Banach space. Then there is a maximising sequence $x_n$ such that $f(x_n) \to \sup_{x \in X}f(x)$, right? Is this sequence countable?

Comment: All sequences are countable... they are indexed by natural numbers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes.  Let $n\in\mathbb{N}$.  Then we can choose $x_n\in X$ so that 
$$f(x_n) > \sup_{x\in X}f(x) - {1\over n}.$$
You have $f(x_n) \to \sup_{x\in X} f(x)$.